# Convert "Any" array to String in swift 3

Tags: swift, casting

Having this code:

```
let object = json as? [Any] {
    if let questionari=object["questionnarie"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{
}
```

Compiler (of course) says to me that I can't use a String's index while it's `[Any]`: I can't find the proper why to cast it as String.

Comment: If `object` is supposed to be an array then the next line won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be casting your json object as so:

```
if let object = json as? [String:Any] {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code-

```
if let object = json as? [String:Any] {
    if let questionari=object["questionnarie"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{
}
```

Comment: Thank you too, but our colleague was faster :)

Answer (score 0):

you can make `componentsJoined` string with `","` from any array.

like one line code see bellow example:

```
let yourStringVar = NSArray(array:ANY_ARRAY_NAME).componentsJoined(by: ",")
```